# AJAX put request failing?

Tags: ajax

Doing an ajax get request works as expected using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   contentType: "application/json",
   url: "http://someSeceretUrl/test/document,
   dataType: "jsonp",
   success: function(msg) {
   console.log(msg);
   },
   error: function(a,b,c) {
     console.log(a);
     console.log(b);
     console.log(c);
}
});
```

But a PUT ajax call using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "PUT",
   contentType: "application/json",
   url: "http://someObscureURL/test/mrmer1",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   data: {"name":"mike"},
   success: function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
   },
   error: function(a,b,c) {
     console.log("XMLHttpRequest: " + a);
     console.log("textStatus: " + b);
     console.log("errorThrown: " + c);
  }
  });
```

results in the following console output:

```
XMLHttpRequest: [object XMLHttpRequest]
textStatus: null
errorThrown: [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4   (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)" location: "http://static.kobj.net/kobj-static-20100219162227.js Line: 371"]
```

I am thinking that something is blocking the PUT request, but I don't know.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are hitting [cross domain restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). I wouldn't be surprised if `http://username:password@somehost` is considered as cross domain.

Answer (score 0):

When I've done PUT requests in the past, I've found that not passing the contentLength header results in an exception being thrown, just a thought